# Store a clients struct and use it afterwards

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I store my clients like this..

```
   int MAXCLIENTS = 4;
   int ClientCount = 0;
   int FreeSpot[MAXCLIENTS];

    typedef struct CLIENTS_FD{

    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in cli_adr;

    }cliuse;

    cliuse MYCLIENTS[4];

do{

    NewSFD = accept(ServerFD,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
              if (NewSFD < 0)
              {
                 if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
                 {
                    perror("  accept() failed");
                    DCSERVER = TRUE;
                 }
                 break;
              }
               if(ClientCount < MAXCLIENTS){
                for(loop = 0; loop < MAXCLIENTS; loop++){

                if(FreeSpot[loop]<0){

                Clients[loop].sock = NewSFD;

                break;

                }

              }

              ClientCount++;
 }
          else
          {

          printf("Maximum Client Reached.\n");
          char *sendtoclient = "Server full";
          send(NewSFD, sendtoclient, strlen(sendtoclient),0);
          close(NewSFD);
          break;

          }

            ip = ntohl(cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
            printf("  Connection from %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
                (int)(ip>>24)&0xff,
                (int)(ip>>16)&0xff,
                (int)(ip>>8)&0xff,
                (int)(ip>>0)&0xff);
                dlogs(ip);


}while(NewSFD != -1);
```

I know i can store my clients file descriptor but how can i store my clients struct and use it afterwards i want to send message to it?.. say i want to send message to client with ip 192.168.5.10.

thanks.

Comment: File descriptor should be all you need to communicate with the client (using `write()` or `send()` or something similar). What do mean by "client's file descriptor" and what are you actually trying to accomplish other than communicate with your client?

Comment: this is not ANSI. MAXCLIENTS is a variable, you shouldn't use it to define a static vector's size. you should use #define MAXCLIENTS 4

Comment: it's what i get after doing accept(new file descriptor for clients)..well the clients are devices.. so i need to know their specific address so i know where to send data to.

Comment: will string comparing the address in my struct work.. then if found send message to that client.

Comment: Normally a server program really doesn't care what addresses clients connect from, and don't send to "client connected from aa.bb.cc.dd". Instead you communicate with "client X" where "X" in your case is `0` to `3` (the indexes in your array). If "client X" sends something that you need to reply to then you send the reply to "client X".

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg - Yes thank you for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss some important point about network programming. Maybe you should read [this](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) for more details and infos how to start.

Nevertheless `accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen)` will fill client addres structure which is second parameter (`struct sockaddr *addr`). You can then easily add this address to your CLIENTS_FD structure.

```
Clients[loop].sock = NewSFD; 

Clients[loop].cli_adr = cli_addr;
```

assuming that Clients is cliuse (or `struct CLIENTS_FD`).

Anyway, like mentioned in some comments above you don't need to store this address anywhere. All you need to communicate with your client is its `sockfd` (which is returned by accept).

What is more there could be some bugs in your code:

```
int FreeSpot[MAXCLIENTS];
```

is uninitialized so when you try to check it

```
if(FreeSpot[loop]<0)
```

this could lead to wrong behaviour. You could simply write `int FreeSpot[MAXCLIENTS] = {0};` You should then somewhere (probably inside `if(FreeSpot[loop]<0)` statement) add something like this `FreeSpot[loop] = 1;` to set it properly before next checks.

```
int MAXCLIENTS = 4; 

int FreeSpot[MAXCLIENTS];
```

Since C99 it is possible to declare tables using something else than constant. This is called VLA (variable length array). Nevertheless in your case I can see no point to use VLA. Try `#define MAXCLIENTS 4` instead (as suggested in some comment above).

To write to the clients, after returning from your do-while loop you can simply use something like below:

```
send(Clients[i].sock, msg, len, flags);
```

where i is number of your client (range 0-3), again assuming that Clients is `cliuse` (or `struct CLIENTS_FD`).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me the right way to do it.. Really Appreciate it.